# Dual driven-element Yagi-Uda antennas

Tags: yagi

Came across the TET-Emtron HB35C antenna which is a:

*"The HB35C is a full size tri-bander, efficiently utilising the DUAL DRIVE HB9CV system with the revolutionary “PHASE TUNED” VK2AOU multi band system."*

I'm sure what they say is true, it's just got me wondering how these features technically  work.

As i understand it the "dual drive hb9cv" is referring to a dual driven-element. A little Googling on dual DE yagi's turned up this info:

> "In this paper, we present a novel design for an end-fire antenna, which generalizes the concept of conventional Yagi-Uda antenna by introducing multiple driven elements. Through using the method of maximum power transmission efficiency, the optimal distribution of excitations for the multiple driven elements can be obtained, and the end-fire gain of the array can be significantly improved in comparison with the conventional Yagi-Uda antenna with a single driven element. In order to demonstrate the new idea, two different types of antenna arrays are designed and fabricated. The first design uses a split-ring resonator (SRR) as radiating element. Compared to similar planar Yagi-Uda SRR antenna arrays previously reported, the number of antenna elements can be reduced from fifteen to eight, and the longitudinal dimension is significantly reduced by 46% while the same performances are maintained with the gain reaching 11.7 dBi at 5.5 GHz. In the second design, printed half-wavelength dipoles are used as the antenna elements. It is shown that an eight-element dipole array with four driven elements has a peak gain of 13.4 dBi at 2.45 GHz, which is 1.8 dB higher than the conventional printed Yagi-Uda dipole antenna array with the same number of elements."

**Reference: Design of Yagi-Uda Antenna with Multiple Driven Elements
By Huadong Guo and Wen Geyi
Progress In Electromagnetics Research C, Vol. 92, 101-112, 2019
doi:10.2528/PIERC19013002**

Perhaps someone can simplify how they would work?

Thanks as always :)

Comment: Remember that Q&A works best when you ask a single question. I advise that you remove the second of your questions even if it is related and ask it in another question.

Comment: Fair call. Question updated.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this old QRZ.com thread:

https://forums.qrz.com/index.php?threads/10m-dual-driven-antenna.165171/

To summarise (in case the link rots), the thread concludes the main reason for dual driven-elements specifically is for an improvement in VSWR bandwidth.

It seems it's roughly a simple form of log-periodic (which makes sense).

Credit to member user10489 who commented in the related question who identified the same. :)