# Phase-tuning Yagi-Uda antennas

Tags: antenna, yagi

Related to [my earlier question around the TET-Emtron HB35C antenna](https://ham.stackexchange.com/q/20787/21417). It is advertised as a:

> The HB35C is a full size tri-bander, efficiently utilising the DUAL
> DRIVE HB9CV system with the revolutionary “PHASE TUNED” VK2AOU multi
> band system.

This question specifically is relating to the latter "phase tuned multi band system".

Why would, and how does one, phase-tune a Yagi antenna?

Link to manufacturers site [2](https://tetemtron.com/product/hb35c/).

Comment: Phase tuning is integral to the design of a yagi... Maybe start here and see if you want to refine the question?  https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/antennas-propagation/yagi-uda-antenna-aerial/theory.php

Comment: Looking at the abstract in your other link, the point here is less that it is high gain than that is is wide bandwidth and fed from multiple driven elements (sounds like a log periodic) and smaller than a conventional yagi.

Comment: Phased tuning usually involves more than one antenna, with the goal of changing the pattern of of the multiple antenna array.

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/posts/20788/edit) and add a link to the manufacturer's website? I'd like to see a picture or diagram of it.

Comment: Thanks Mark, see last sentence & link.

Answer (score 1):

I would be highly suspicious of anything with a description like that especially if it has the call sign of a supposed amateur radio expert in it. The term "Phase Tuned" could mean anything, and i doubt that the "system" in question is anywhere near being revolutionary.

In fact technically speaking you could argue that a standard yagi antenna is phase tuned as everything about the dimensions of a yagi relate to the phase of the signals it works with to some degree.

As another example of a dubious revolutionary new antenna discovery, I recent purchased a 4 element quad which has a patented SFS Signal Feed System which i imagine was designed by a ham radio expert, and this antenna is basically a piece of junk which i didn't even bother assembling, and is now an expensive AUD$1200 pile of spare parts which i can't use for anything sitting under my house.

Apologies for the negative answer, but i would steer clear and not waste any time on these grandoise claims by ham radio operators regarding some new invention that no one else has apparently ever thought about yet.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, appreciate your point, and it's a valid one. The bit i can verify is the dual driven element is a real thing (see related link above), but wether it adds much more gain to be noticeable is something i'm not sure about. The jury is still out on the phase-tuned part (and something i need to learn more about), but TET-Emtron are a reputable company so it has me on the fence to learn more about the underlying tech. I think there's a lot of snake-oil out there as you mention but i do think there's some genuine innovation too, so far the dual DE is the only part i can corroborate.